# How do I get the text after a date using python?

Tags: python, string, date, named-entity-recognition

I have a string which might have a date of some form inside it.

I want to extract the portion appearing just after that date.

For example:

```
s = "The term starts on Jan 1, 2000 and terminates on"
```

should return

```
output = "and terminates on"
```

My suggestion would be

```
s[s.find(', 2') + 6]
```

Comment: Look into the regular expression with `re`.

Comment: I have been put into question ban, and I want to escape it. This is a low ranked question. So can I improve this question and therefore get out of the ban? What is a way to improve this question? I don't know why it was down-ranked....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) with `fuzzy_with_tokens=True`

**Ex:**

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
s = "The term starts on Jan 1, 2000 and terminates on"
print(parse(s, fuzzy_with_tokens=True))
```

**Output:**

```
(datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0), ('The term starts on ', ' ', ' ', 'and terminates on'))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it.

```
s = "The term starts on Jan 1, 2000 and terminates on"
ss = s.split('0')
output = ss[-1]
```